# Gradle Kotlin Dsl - How to share utility functions

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I wrote this:

```
fun Properties.toStringMap(): Map<String, String> =
    this.toMap().map { it.key.toString() to it.value.toString() }.toMap()

tasks.withType<JavaExec> {
    systemProperties = System.getProperties().toStringMap()
}
```

It would be useful to have this toStringMap() function across my 50+ repos, but I'm not sure how to package it.  My first thought was to put in a plugin script, but it's not available at compile time.  So a fail.  I googled around, found nothing, and decided to ask people smarter than myself.

Any ideas?

Comment: "but it's not available at compile time." What do you mean by that? If you write a plugin (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) then the plugin code is available in the build script. Or do want to use code in your build scripts and your regular Kotlin programs?

Comment: Well, that is true for a compiled plugin, but not for a script plugin

Comment: yes, I have script plugin.   Okay, compiled plugin.  Sounds fun.